# Why Wiener filter not IIR

Tags: filters, discrete-signals, finite-impulse-response, infinite-impulse-response, wiener-filter

I would like to limit discussion to discrete time causal Wiener filter.

By definition it is an FIR filter, and it also has optimality under Mean Square Error criterion within the class of linear filters.

How do we know that there isn't a better IIR filter (something with a feedback loop), which is also linear?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right, there usually *is* a better IIR filter (if you have enough data). The discrete-time Wiener filter is not "by definition" FIR. It is common to constrain the filter to the FIR case because it's often more straightforward to implement, and because such a filter can be made adaptive more easily. Also, in practice you often want to consider only a finite data window, which makes the optimum Wiener filter FIR.

However, you don't need to impose the constraint that the filter length be finite. The most general causal discrete-time Wiener filter for data available over the infinite past is an IIR filter.

A derivation of the FIR and the IIR cases can be found (among others) in *Digital Signal Processing* by Proakis and Manolakis.

EDIT: If we only have a finite amount of data available, the optimum Wiener filter has a finite impulse response. Assume we have $N$ data points (one current and $N-1$ consecutive past data points), then the best we can do with a linear time-invariant filter is to linearly combine those $N$ data points, by multiplying each data point by a coefficient and adding them up:

$$y[n]=\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}h[k]x[n-k]\tag{1}$$

The coefficients $h[k]$ are optimized such that the mean square error between the filter output $y[n]$ and some desired signal is minimized. The $N$ coefficients $h[k]$ are the impulse response of the corresponding FIR Wiener filter.

Comment: @CowboyTrader: For the IIR Wiener filter the data sequence is assumed to be infinite.

Comment: @CowboyTrader: The book I mentioned is generally a good book on DSP, not only about discrete-time filters. But it does have a lot of good stuff on filters.

Comment: @CowboyTrader: As an IIR filter it's both, so it takes infinitely many past values into account, but it can be expressed recursively.

Comment: @CowboyTrader: If you only have $N$ data points, you can only linearly combine them using $N$ coefficients, so the optimal filter must be FIR. This doesn't say anything about implementation, but as a filter it must have a finite impulse response.

Comment: @CowboyTrader: Using recursion you will either get infinite memory - no use for finite data - or, in the degenerate case, finite memory, which could also be implemented without recursion.

Comment: Cowboy Trader: Note that the Kalman filter formulation represents a "one period ahead response". Therefore, formulated as a Kalman filter, the impulse response, if you will is one period. In fact,  the :impulse response" terminology is not really used for the KF because it's not really the correct terminology to use because the impulse response is made up of only one period. So, as Matt L said, if you have only a finite number of say , N, data points, then you only have an impulse response that spans N periods. So it too is finite and the KF can  be thought of as an FIR.filter.

Comment: @Cownoy Trader: Note that I can't comment on the Wiener filter because I'm still learning about it but I think the "one step ahead"  concept is the same there. Sounds like I should be looking at Proakis and Manolikas..

Comment: @CowboyTrader: I've added some information to my answer. I hope it's clear now.

Comment: @CowboyTrader: "... even if we have finite data we can design an IIR filter that may be better than the FIR filter". Show it, I can't see how.

Comment: For example a standard y(t) = a*y(t-1) + (1-a)*x(t). I don't understand why we need infinite data to use such a filter. Are we discussing an initialization issue?

Comment: @CowboyTrader: I don't say that you need infinite data to run an IIR filter. It's about optimizing the filter coefficients. The filter in your example has infinite memory, but for a finite data set we can't do any better than use memory that just spans the length of the given finite data set. So a system with such finite memory must be optimal, looking further into the past (where we have not data) cannot help improving the filter performance.

Comment: @CowboyTrader: You misunderstand what is meant by memory of a system. I don't mean the memory that is needed for *implementing* a system, I mean the memory of the system with respect to its input. Your simple first order IIR filter has infinite memory (IIR=infinite impulse response, as you probably know). Infinite impulse response means that theoretically the filter never forgets what happened at its input. I really think you should read up on filters and DSP, I've tried to help but I can't explain in an answer and a few comments the background that you seem to be missing.

Comment: @CowboyTrader: " ... there is really no point to estimate an N lag FIR filter, because it is not doable". Well, many people have done that and are still doing it ...

Comment: Thanks. I actually understood the situation. Yes we can estimate an N lag filter with N data points but the estimates will be very poor without some sort of regularization. So the bottom line is that given N data points an N lag FIR is the maximum one will need(although it makes sense I will try to find a proof for this) This also assumes that the unseen new data(not the data we used to estimate the weights) to filter will also have to be maximum this size. Right?

Comment: @CowboyTrader: Yes, in this case you always have a buffer with the last $N$ data points, and you forget all older ones. As for the proof of the FIR property, it's somehow obvious; say you want to linearly combine two numbers, then you'll need two coefficients. Even if you get a third and a fourth one for free you can't use them in any way (if you restrict yourself to linear combination, i.e., to linear time-invariant filtering).

Comment: Thank you very much. One last thing. So when the data finishes you will have some zeros in the tail. For those optimality drops I assume.

Comment: @CowboyTrader: Yes, in principle you base everything on a continuous input of data. Those end effects can usually be neglected.